# id_rsa.pub is empty when created by ssh-keygen -t rsa

Tags: shell, unix, ssh-keys

I am trying to create id_rsa.pub file using the below command.
ssh-keygen -t rsa

Put the .pub file created under the .ssh folder is empty. It's of 0 bytes.

Can i know why it's create  an empty file?

I have 3 other server where the .pub file had the key generated properlty. This issue is only with one if the servers.

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: There is no error message. The file is getting created.

Comment: Even `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 256` creates an empty key ?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing code. Requests for keygen debuggin, tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: This is actually happened due to space issue. After making some empty space, the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem because there is **no disk space** left on my machine.

Just delete some files and try again.

Hope it will be helpful.